# Increase Stack size IIS ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-3.5

I understand that the default max stack size on ASP.NET was decreased to 256K instead of 1MB (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932909), how can I get it back to 1MB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [editbin](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx), as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: For those who try this and get errors when calling `EDITBIN`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980028/editbin-gives-lnk1104-cannot-open-file/21378546#21378546

Answer (score 6):

Another solution could be that of creating an explicit new thread to perform the operations where you're getting a stack overflow error

```
  Thread t = new Thread(Run, 4194304); // 4M of stack size
  t.Start();
  t.Join();
  if (loadException != null) throw loadException;

  void Run()
        {
            try
            {
              // Operation causing stack overflow
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              ...
            }
        }
```

Regards

Massimo

Comment: I'm calling the an external unmanged dll, and still getting a stackoverflow..., maybe when u call an unmanged dll, the stack size goes back to 256k?